# Linq - unable to join table due to null value

Tags: linq

I am having problem with joining of multiple tables.
PatientID can be null. Whenever patientID is null, it is unable to join and the result will not be added to the list.

Any suggestion on how i can do to join them ?

```
        List<ViewActivityLogViewModel> q = new List<ViewActivityLogViewModel>();

        q = (from l in logs
                 join lc in logCategories on l.logCategoryID equals lc.logCategoryID
                 join p in patients on l.patientID equals p.patientID
                 join u in users on l.userIDInit equals u.userID
                 join ut in usertypes on u.userTypeID equals ut.userTypeID
                 join u2 in users on l.userIDApproved equals u2.userID
                 join ut2 in usertypes on u2.userTypeID equals ut2.userTypeID
                 select new ViewActivityLogViewModel
                 {
                    logID = l.logID,
                    logCategoryName =lc.logCategoryName,
                    firstName = p.firstName,
                    userIDInitfirstName = u.firstName,
                    userIDInituserTypeName = ut.userTypeName,
                    userIDApprovedfirstName = u2.firstName,
                    userIDApproveduserTypeName = ut2.userTypeName
                 }
                 ).OrderBy(x=>x.createDateTime).ToList();
```

This is the answer i need. I written it in SQL.

```
SELECT l.logID, lc.logCategoryName,p.firstName, p.lastName, u.firstName, ut.userTypeName,   u2.firstName,  ut2.userTypeName
FROM log AS l
LEFT JOIN patient AS p ON l.patientID = p.patientID
JOIN logCategory AS lc ON l.logCategoryID = lc.logCategoryID
JOIN user AS u ON l.userIDInit = u.userID
JOIN userType AS ut ON u.userTypeID = ut.userTypeID
JOIN user AS u2 ON l.userIDApproved = u2.userID
JOIN userType AS ut2 ON u2.userTypeID = ut2.userTypeID
```

Comment: users/usertypes is obtained from log.userIDInit. I am trying GroupJoin/Left Join now... very difficult to understand the help provided online.

Comment: In a well designed database with relations set, you very rarely need join keyword. Why wouldn't you simply use navigational properties instead?

Comment: @user9839473 where is the CreatedTime comes from? Is this a columns of Log table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupJoin` to join the `patients` table and get the data. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.110).aspx), `GroupJoin` in `Lambda` supports the `LEFT JOIN` in `SQL`.

> GroupJoin preserves the order of the elements of outer, and for each
>   element of outer, the order of the matching elements from inner.
>
> GroupJoin has no direct equivalent in
>   traditional relational database terms. However, this method does
>   implement a superset of inner joins and left outer joins. Both of
>   these operations can be written in terms of a grouped join.

So, your query can be written as,

```
 var results = 
            logs.Join(logCategories, l => l.logCategoryID, lc => lc.logCategoryID, (l, lc) => new { l, lc })
            .Join(users, llc => new { userId = llc.l.userIDInit }, u1 => new { userId = u1.userID }, (llc, u1) => new { llc.l, llc.lc, u1 })
            .Join(userTypes, llcu1 => llcu1.u1.userTypeID, ut1 => ut1.userTypeID, (llcu1, ut1) => new { llcu1.l, llcu1.lc, llcu1.u1, ut1 })
            .Join(users, llcu2 => new { approvedId = llcu2.l.userIDApproved }, u2 => new { approvedId = u2.userID }, (llcu2, u2) => new { llcu2.l, llcu2.lc, llcu2.u1, llcu2.ut1, u2 })
            .Join(userTypes, llcu3 => llcu3.u2.userTypeID, ut2 => ut2.userTypeID, (llcu3, ut2) => new { llcu3.l, llcu3.lc, llcu3.u1, llcu3.u2, llcu3.ut1, ut2 })
            .GroupJoin(patients, llcu4 => llcu4.l.patientID, p => p.patientID, (llcu4, p) => new { llcu4.l, llcu4.lc, llcu4.u1, llcu4.u2, llcu4.ut1, llcu4.ut2, p })
            .SelectMany(x => x.p.DefaultIfEmpty(), (prj, y) => 
            {
                return new ViewActivityLogViewModel
                {
                    logID = prj.l.logID,
                    logCategoryName = prj.lc.logCategoryName,
                    firstName = y != null ? y.firstName : null,
                    userIDInitfirstName = prj.u1.firstName,
                    userIDInituserTypeName = prj.ut1.userTypeName,
                    userIDApprovedfirstName = prj.u2.firstName,
                    userIDApproveduserTypeName = prj.ut2.userTypeName
                };
            }).ToList();
```

[C# Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTZKV9) with sample data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure  why did u
replicated the joins which could be achieved in two joins only

```
JOIN user AS u ON l.userIDInit = u.userID
JOIN userType AS ut ON u.userTypeID = ut.userTypeID
JOIN user AS u2 ON l.userIDApproved = u2.userID
JOIN userType AS ut2 ON u2.userTypeID = ut2.userTypeID
```

as

```
JOIN user AS u ON l.userIDInit = u.userID and l.userIDApproved = u.userID
JOIN userType AS ut ON u.userTypeID = ut.userTypeID
```

The below query will give u ur desired result

```
q = (from l in log
     join lc in logCategory
          on l.logCategoryID equals lc.logCategoryID
     join u in user 
          on new {a1=l.userIDInit,a2=l.userIDApproved} equals 
             new {a1=u.userID, a2=u.userID}
     join ut in userType
          on u.userTypeID equals ut.userTypeID
     join p in patient
          on l.patientID equals p.patientID
         into p11
     from p1 in p11.DefaultIfEmpty()
     select new {l,lc,u,ut,p1})
     .Select(x=>new ViewActivityLogViewModel
                {
                    logID = x.l.logID,
                    logCategoryName =x.lc.logCategoryName,
                    firstName = x.p1?.firstName,
                    userIDInitfirstName = x.u.firstName,
                    userIDInituserTypeName = x.ut.userTypeName,
                    userIDApprovedfirstName = x.u.firstName,
                    userIDApproveduserTypeName = x.ut.userTypeName
                 })
      .OrderBy(x=>x.createDateTime).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which PatientId can be null, so to be on the safe side I assume both can be null.

```
q = (from l in logs
     join lc in logCategories.Where(category => category.PatientId != null)
             on l.logCategoryID equals lc.logCategoryID

     join p in patients where(patient => patien.PatiendId != null)
             on l.patientID equals p.patientID

     join ...
```